# Trying to malloc a typedef 2d array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, memory-management

I've declared a typedef:

```
typedef float Matrix[3][3];
```

And I'm now trying to allocate memory for that array:

```
Matrix* matPtr = malloc(sizeof(Matrix));

if (matPtr != NULL)
{
    for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++)
        {
            *matPtr[r][c] = 0; 
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm getting the error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Warning C6200   Index '2' is out of valid index range '0' to '0' for non-stack buffer 'matPtr'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `*matPtr[r][c]` --> `(*matPtr)[r][c]` . The subscript operator `[ ]` has higher [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than the dereference operator `*`. Applied to the same id in the same expression without parenthetical distinction is gonna hurt.

Comment: Or `float (*matPtr)[3] = malloc(sizeof(Matrix));` and then you can use `matPtr[r][c] = 0;` and not have to worry about missing parentheses.

Comment: To clarify, the declaration `Matrix *matPtr = malloc(sizeof(Matrix));` is equivalent to an array declaration like `float mat[1][3][3]`. Which means that accessing the array elements needs to be either `(*matPtr)[r][c]=0` or `matPtr[0][r][c]=0`. The correct pointer type for `malloc(sizeof(Matrix))` is actually `float (*matPtr)[3]`, which allows you to access the array elements with `matPtr[r][c]=0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Do not hide arrays and pointers behind typedefs. It is a very very bad practice.
2. Use pointers to array

```
int (*matrix)[3] = malloc(3 * sizeof(*matrix));
```

and use as a normal matrix

```
matrix[1][2] = 5;
```